# No friends can see what i shared on facebook (through android)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, android-sharing

I created a music player. In the app, there is a feature where user can share what songs they are listening to. I STRICTLY followed [this official guide from facebook's developer's page.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) Sharing is working fine. But none of my friends can see the shared posts. I have uploaded a screenshot showing the posts i shared on facebook. I have tried changing the privacy setting of the post from "friends" to "public"/others. But nothing seems to work.

Am i missing something?

Here is the code snippet:

```
    fbIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ListItem item = PlayerService.listItems.get(PlayerService.currentSongIndex);



            if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
                String desc = "I'm listening to: " + item.getTitle() + ", " + item.getAlbum() + " by " + item.getArtist();
                ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                        .setContentTitle("G-Music Station")
                        .setContentDescription(desc)
                        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com"))
                        .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("http://radiogbd.com//images/logo.png"))
                        .build();


                ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(PlayerActivity.this);
                shareDialog.show(linkContent);

            }
        }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Also from the link provided "When someone shares from your app, their content appears on their Timeline and **may** appear in their friends' News Feeds."

Comment: No the app is not live. The posts are appearing on my timeline but my friends cant see it when they visit my timeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable the sandbox mode in your app settings in order for your friends to see the post(s).